# Get multiple getElementById using javascript form

Tags: javascript, forms, getelementbyid

I have to create a form using javascript which return a message error displayed inline if the field is empty.
In my code below only the first one runs I cannot set up the postcode one.
(I am not allowed to use Jquery)
Thank you for your time

```
function checkForm() {
    document.getElementById("frm1").onsubmit = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("lastname").value === "") {
            showError();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function checkForm() {
    document.getElementById("frm1").onsubmit = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("postCod").value === "") {
            showError();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function showError() {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "inline";
}
window.onload = checkForm;
```

Comment: you have two functions with the same name....only one will ever be called

Comment: You've declared two functions with exactly the same name. The result is that there'll be only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can have only one function with mutliple `if-else` statements.

```
   function checkForm() {
    document.getElementById("frm1").onsubmit = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("lastname").value === "") {
            showError();
            return false;
        } else  if (document.getElementById("postCod").value === "") {
            showError();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
 }

function showError() {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "inline";
}
window.onload = checkForm;
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried it but nothing occurs for the postcode field when it is empty

Comment: It will work when lastname has value and postcod is empty... can u try this?

Comment: Now the error message appear wether the last name has value next to its field.

Comment: no unfortunately I am browsing all around the web to solve this problem. The error message appears whatever if the field is empty or not but only for the last name field, nothing for the postcode

Comment: Issue resolved!!! I had to change the name of my id selector error into error2 in html and add it in my CSS + add a second declaration===>document.getElementById("error2").style.display = "inline";
} Thank you again for your time. good evening

Answer (score 0):

I would consolidate the two functions into one like so:

```
function checkForm() {
    document.getElementById("frm1").onsubmit = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("lastname").value === "") {
            showError();
            return false;
        } else if (document.getElementById("postCod").value === "") {
            showError();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you beat me by seconds :)

Comment: I tried your code but I still have the same problem here the css I use for error== > #error {
display:none;
color: red;
padding-left: 1em;
} and here the html===> <label for="postCod">Postcodes: </label>
    <input type="text" id="postCod"> <span id="error">*Please Enter a postcode</span>

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it from `onsubmit` to `addEventListener`. This is because using `.onsubmit` is like an object property when you set it equal to something it overrides the value. Using `addEventListener` allows you to have multilpe functions bound to the same event.

```
var form = document.getElementById("frm1")

form.addEventListener("submit", function () {
  // do something
})
```

Comment: sorry I am a beginner I did not learn this way so far, I have no clue how to implement it

Comment: I would just have one Fn named checkForm, the other answers. But the answer to your question, about why you can't have two onsubmit's is my answer.

Comment: It is the layout of the form I want,